# Converting date to unix with milliseconds precision in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, unix

I am currently trying to convert a few dates in Javascript however these dates are defined with milliseconds and that data cannot be lost when converted.
I have tried doing the following

```
var dateString = '2009-07-15 11:00:00.675';
dateString = dateString.split(' ').join('T');
var date = new Date(dateString);
date = date.getTime() / 1000;
```

But date returns

```
date= 1247655600.675
```

I have read a few topics in stack overflow but the only "solution" I saw was the following:

```
parseInt((new Date('2012.08.10').getTime() / 1000).toFixed(0))
```

But this does not consider milliseconds either.
What should I do to correctly convert a date to unix timestamp with milliseconds precision?

Thank you.

Comment: A Date's time value is milliseconds, dividing by 1,000 gives seconds. So just don't divide by 1000.

Comment: `1247655600.675` has a precision of milliseconds, but the units are seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, no need to do /1000

```
var dateString = '2009-07-15 11:00:00.675';
dateString = dateString.split(' ').join('T');
var date = new Date(dateString);
date = date.getTime();
```